# Scala - what does the &> operator do?

Tags: scala, operator-keyword

I'm only just learning scala and I see existing code using an operator: &> and I cannot find anything with google search. I don't understand what it is doing.

Code snippet:

```
Ok.feed(producer &>  EventSource()).as("text/event-stream")
```

Comment: is it from Play framework?

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumeratee

Comment: That's it! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a metod of `Enumeratee` trait and as docs says is an alias for `apply` method. Which is also an alias for `applyOn` which by [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumeratee) :

> Create a new Iteratee that feeds its input, potentially modifying it
>   along the way, into the inner Iteratee, and produces that Iteratee as
>   its result.